# I'm getting a string in my list which should be a list

Tags: python, list

I'm reading a csv file from my python code and expecting it to return a list of lists but I'm getting a list which contains a str. Can somebody tell me how I can convert it into a list thanks.

This is the code which is reading my csv file from my local directory.

```
with open('/home/developer/Desktop/csv/JE_csv/JP_Preisliste_GreenHome_Select_ab_29-10.2021.csv', encoding='utf-8-sig') as csv_data:
    PriceListGetAG = list(csv.reader(csv_data, delimiter=';'))
    for elem in range(0, len(GreenHomeSelect_PriceListGetAG), 1):
    print(PriceListGetAG[elem])
```

**This is what I'm getting.**

```
["'14844', '26.10.2021', 'JP_C24_002', 'GreenHome Select', '01067'"]
```

**This is what my expected output should be.**

```
['14844', '26.10.2021', 'JP_C24_002', 'GreenHome Select', '01067']
```

Comment: Please include the code which generated this single string list.

Comment: Well, does your CSV file actually use `;` as a delimiter?

Answer (score 1):

I think your delimeter is comma. Change your parameter like this.

```
delimiter=','
```